# Multiple models in one form using EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a simple multi model form using .net 4.5, Entity 5, MVC 4

Based on examples I have seen I expect EditorTemplates\Tasks.cshtml  to be rendered twice, once for each Task in the Project, but it only appears to get called once and passed a collection of Tasks which I seem to be unable to work with.

Any ideas?  My classes/views are listed below.

Task:

```
public partial class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.TaskPeople = new HashSet<TaskPerson>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TaskPerson> TaskPeople { get; set; }
}
```

Project:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.New():

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    Project project = new Project();
    project.Tasks.Add(new Task() { });
    project.Tasks.Add(new Task() { });
    return View(project);
}
```

Home/New.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()    
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)    
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tasks, "Tasks")
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Home/EditorTemplates/Tasks.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication5.Models.Task>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) // Error Here
```

EDIT:

If I take IEnumerable out of Tasks.cshtml and replace it with

```
@model MvcApplication5.Models.Task
```

I get the following exception:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[MvcApplication5.Models.Task]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication5.Models.Task'.
```

Comment: The tasks.cshtml shouldn't need to be an IEnumerable<Task> just Task - just put the base type and the razor engine will render the list of m.Tasks -that's how the templates are designed to work. And change the name of the template to Task.cshtml as it matches on the Type. This will also ensure that the form field ids are correctly indexed for passing to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

In `Home/EditorTemplates/Tasks.cshtml`, the model is `IEnumerable` however, to render the textbox, you are not looping through the list.

Not sure how you are not getting a run-time error when you try to access the `Title` property since that property does not exist in the `IEnumerable<MvcApplication5.Models.Task>`

Comment: I actually am getting an error there, updated view code above to show this

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of templates is a little off, so let me see if I can help.

The `Html.Display*` and `Html.Editor*` helpers are all capable of recognising when you're passing them a collection.  Instead of you having to loop over that collection, those methods will repeatedly call a template for the underlying type of a collection, for each element of that collection.

In plain English, if you pass a `List<Car>` to one of those methods, if the `Car.cshtml` template exists, it will repeatedly invoke that template for every `Car` in that list.  In your case that means changing your code to something like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()    
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)    
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tasks)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Then the template `Task.cshtml`:

```
@model MvcApplication5.Models.Task

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
```

Comment: Thanks John.  I expected it to work the way you just described but I get an exception:  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[MvcApplication5.Models.Task]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication5.Models.Task'

Comment: @recursive_acronym I just tried using your exact model and controller code with the template I defined above and it's working correctly.

Comment: Did you leave the initializer as a Hashset?

Comment: @recursive_acronym Yeah, I did.  I've uploaded a copy of the solution [here](http://www.filedropper.com/192357342).  Ignore the weird naming of the solution; it's the ID of this question on SO and the `_2` is because it was my second attempt. (I tried in MVC 3 first, not realising you'd tagged this as MVC 4.)  See if that helps you to narrow it down.

Comment: none of my programs can open that zip file.  Thanks so much for trying! :)

Comment: @recursive_acronym Huh, really?  I can try uploading it as a .rar or something if you'd like.  I have 20Mbps upload so it wouldn't take very long.

Comment: That would be great, as long as its not much trouble

Comment: @recursive_acronym It's no trouble mate.  I'll try and find a different host and upload it as a .rar file.

Comment: @recursive_acronym Alright, try [this link](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/etZQdPWy38/).  It shows all the contents of the archive, too.

Comment: All fixed.   I took the template name out of "EditorFor(m => m.Tasks)"  and renamed the EditorTemplate from Tasks to Task (so I didn't need to provide the template name)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38754/discussion-between-recursive-acronym-and-john-h)

Answer (score 0):

This the model

```
public class TSubject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
public class TMonth
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}


public class TModel
{
    public List<TSubject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public List<TMonth> Months { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Test1()
    {
        TModel model = new TModel
        {
            Months = new List<TMonth>
            {
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = false, Title = "January"
                },
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = true, Title = "Feburary"
                },
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = false, Title = "March"
                },
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = true, Title = "April"
                },
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = true, Title = "May"
                },
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = false, Title = "June"
                },
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = false, Title = "July"
                },
                new TMonth
                {
                    IsSelected = true, Title = "August"
                },
            },
            Subjects = new List<TSubject>
            {
                new TSubject
                {
                    Title = "Biology", IsSelected = false, 
                },
                new TSubject
                {
                    Title = "Chemistry", IsSelected = false,
                },
                new TSubject
                {
                    Title = "Physics", IsSelected = true,
                },
                new TSubject
                {
                    Title = "English", IsSelected = false,
                },
                new TSubject
                {
                    Title = "Urdu", IsSelected = false,
                },
                new TSubject
                {
                    Title = "Islamic Studies", IsSelected = true,
                },
            }
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test1(TModel mod)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "All OK";
        }
        return View(mod);
    }
```

HTML View

```
@model ZiaratToursMVC.ZiaratModels.TModel

<h1>Subject list</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Is selected</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Subjects)
    </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<h1>Month list</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Is selected</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Months)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

TMonth.cs EditorTemplate

```
@model ZiaratToursMVC.ZiaratModels.TMonth

<tr>
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Title)
    @Model.Title
</td>
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a.IsSelected)
</td>
```

TSubject.cs EditorTemplate

```
@model ZiaratToursMVC.ZiaratModels.TSubject

<tr>
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Title)
    @Model.Title
</td>
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a.IsSelected)
</td>
```